# javascript loop variable substituion

Tags: javascript, variables, loops

I need to use the javascript loop variable i in the loop block.

```
    for (i=0; i<=4; i++)
        {
            status=!status; 
            document.Form_Users.DefaultUser1_UserName.disabled = status;
            document.Form_Users.DefaultUser1_Password.disabled = status;
        }
```

what i need is :

```
       document.Form_Users.DefaultUser{i}_UserName.disabled = status;
```

ie, I could substitute the value of i insted of 1.

I thank all of you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion:

Give them all the same name like
`DefaultUser_UserName[]`
`DefaultUser_Password[]`

then you can look over  document.Form_Users["DefaultUser_UserName[]"]

and if you use PHP on the backend, you even get the array for free

```
function enable_text(status)
  var defaultUsers = document.Form_Users["DefaultUser_UserName[]"];
  var defaultUsers = document.Form_Users["DefaultUser_Password[]"];
  status=!status; 
  for (var i=0, n=defaultUsers.length; i<n; i++) {
    defaultUsers[i].disabled = status;
    defaultPass[i].disabled = status;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (i=1; i<5; i++)
    {
        status=!status; 
        document.Form_Users['DefaultUser'+i+'_UserName'].disabled = status;
        document.Form_Users['DefaultUser'+i+'_Password'].disabled = status;
    }
```

The loop starts with 1 and ends after 4.

Comment: Thanks, But is doen't produce what i need. Your code output such as       function enable_text(status)
        {
            for (i=0; i<=4; i++)
            {
                status=!status;
                document.Form_Users["DefaultUser" + i + "_UserName"].disabled = status;
                document.Form_Users["DefaultUser" + i + "_Password"].disabled = status;
            }
        }

Comment: @mplungjan Added the whole shabang with `i` starting at `1` in the loop. Make sense?

Comment: Remove the status from inside the loop or every second will be disabled

Comment: @mplungjan yes it will be disabled!!

Comment: No - every SECOND element will be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out

```
document.Form_Users["DefaultUser"+i+"_UserName"]["disabled"] = status;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
document.Form_Users["DefaultUser" + i + "_UserName"].disabled = status;
document.Form_Users["DefaultUser" + i + "_Password"].disabled = status;
```